# Python IDDFS missing potential results

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search, traversal, graph-traversal

I'm using bfs and iddfs to find the optimal solution of the 8 tile puzzle, however, my IDDFS is missing solutions and i'm not sure why. ive checked and it seems that every node visits all it's sons, atleast in the first iteration, so i'm not sure what the source of the problem might be. with the tiles arranged as [1,4,5,0,8,2,3,6,7] my iddfs does not seem to find the correct solution at the appropriate depth, and stumbles upon another solution later:
bfs
solution path:
[1, 4, 5, 2, 8, 5, 4, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 1]

iddfs
solution path:
[8, 2, 5, 4, 1, 8, 2, 1, 8, 2, 1, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1]

note that my iddfs k (depth) is increased by intervals of 1, so i should have found the optimal solution at the same depth my bfs did, meaning at the earliest possible depth.
i'm adding the iddfs code and the rest of the code needed to run it below:

```
    # helper method for the iddfs, solves a dfs to a limited depth k
    def dfs_solve_k(self, node, depth):
        if depth < 0:
            return False

        self.total_count += 1
        board_tuple = tuple(tuple(row) for row in node.board_array)
        self.explored.add(board_tuple)

        if node.check_end_state():
            return True

        # Iterate over possible swap positions in a specific order
        for swappable_pos in node.possible_swap_positions:
            tracker = node.board_array[swappable_pos.i][swappable_pos.j]

            # Perform swap to reach a new board
            new_board = node.swap(swappable_pos)
            new_board_tuple = tuple(tuple(row) for row in new_board)

            # Check if the new board state has not been explored before
            if new_board_tuple not in self.explored:
                new_node = StateNode(new_board, swappable_pos)
                is_solved = self.dfs_solve_k(new_node, depth - 1)

                if is_solved:
                    self.path.append(tracker)
                    return True

        return False

    # iterative deepening dfs
    def iddfs(self, node, max_depth):
        search_depth = 1

        while search_depth <= max_depth:
            self.explored.clear()
            self.path = []
            is_solved = self.dfs_solve_k(node, search_depth)

            if is_solved:
                self.path = self.path[::-1]
                return True
            else:
                search_depth += 1
        return False
```

additional code for testing:

```
rows = 3
columns = 3
goal_state = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]


class Position:
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j


class Directions(Enum):
    LEFT = Position(0, -1)
    RIGHT = Position(0, 1)
    UP = Position(-1, 0)
    DOWN = Position(1, 0)


def get_inv_count(board):
    inv_count = 0
    empty_value = 0
    n = len(board)

    for i in range(n * n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n * n):
            row_i, col_i = divmod(i, n)
            row_j, col_j = divmod(j, n)

            val_i = board[row_i][col_i]
            val_j = board[row_j][col_j]

            if val_i != empty_value and val_j != empty_value and val_i > val_j:
                inv_count += 1

    return inv_count


# This function returns true if the given puzzle is solvable.
def is_solvable(puzzle):
    # Count inversions in the given puzzle
    inv_count = get_inv_count(puzzle)

    # Return true if the inversion count is even.
    return inv_count % 2 == 0


def find_position(value, board):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i][j] == value:
                return Position(i, j)


def calculate_distance(position1, position2):
    x1, y1 = position1
    x2 = position2.i
    y2 = position2.j
    distance = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
    return distance


def heuristic(board_state):
    distance_score = 0

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            cell_value = board_state[i][j]
            if cell_value != 0:  # Skip the empty tile (represented by 0)
                target_position = find_position(cell_value, goal_state)
                current_position = (i, j)
                distance = calculate_distance(current_position, target_position)
                distance_score += distance

    return distance_score


class StateNode:
    def __init__(self, board, zero_pos, score=0, parent=None):
        self.board_array = board
        self.zero_pos = zero_pos
        self.score = score
        self.possible_swap_positions = []
        self.parent_node = parent

        for direction in Directions:
            new_zero_pos = Position(self.zero_pos.i + direction.value.i,
                                    self.zero_pos.j + direction.value.j)
            if (
                    0 <= new_zero_pos.i < len(self.board_array) and
                    0 <= new_zero_pos.j < len(self.board_array)
            ):
                self.possible_swap_positions.append(new_zero_pos)

    def get_value(self, position):
        return self.board_array[position.i][position.j]

    def swap(self, swappable_pos):
        # deep copy our array
        new_board = deepcopy(self.board_array)
        temp_value = self.board_array[swappable_pos.i][swappable_pos.j]
        # change current zero to value in new position
        new_board[self.zero_pos.i][self.zero_pos.j] = temp_value
        # change swapped position to zero
        new_board[swappable_pos.i][swappable_pos.j] = 0
        return new_board

    def check_end_state(self):
        for board_row, end_state_row in zip(self.board_array, goal_state):
            if board_row != end_state_row:
                return False

        return True


class GameBoard:
    def __init__(self, values_array):
        self.total_count = 0
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.path = []
        self.explored = set()
        expected_size = rows * columns
        self.game_board = [[0] * columns for _ in range(rows)]
        # Check if the dimensions of values_array match the dimensions of the game_board
        try:
            values_array = [int(value) for value in values_array]
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("All elements in values_array must be convertible to integers.")
        if len(values_array) == expected_size:
            self.game_board = [values_array[i:i + self.columns] for i in range(0, expected_size, self.columns)]
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "The dimensions of the provided values_array do not match the dimensions of the game board.")
```

Comment: When you trace this with a debugger, what is the *first* instruction that doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: i'm having issues debugging with a debugger because the recursion is throwing me around nodes, but it seems like each node calls all its children. @ScottHunter

Comment: But does it do the right *thing* with each of its children?

Comment: looks like it but I can't follow the recursion enough. for other starting boards it does get the same optimal solution as bfs, not for this arrangmenet @ScottHunter

Comment: At the end of def dfs_solve_k your tracker only records the value of the tile moved at each step, not the entire state of the board or the specific move made. Maybe this is not enough to reconstruct the full sequence of moves, especially if the same tile value is moved multiple times in different directions throughout the solution path

Comment: its not a problem because we have to switch a 0 for the tile, so only the tile value is enough - we know it is always swapped with the 0. it's not whats causing the program to miss solutions i think @Miles

Comment: ive followed up to depth 3 which took a while, but anyways it seems like all nodes look for all possible friends which don't exist already in the set. i'm struggling to see what im missing @ScottHunter

Comment: Presumably `iddfs` considers the correct solution/path (if you are correct that it isn't missing any); focus on why it gets rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful how you define whether a state has been explored or not.
There might be a longer path that has a different start, reaches a intermediate state shared with your solution path before finally reaching the solution state.
When running DFS at a the maximum depth of your solution (here 15), you might follow first this longer path and visit the intermediate state but without being able to reach the final state, as the length of the alternative path exceeds 15.
Then when following the first steps of your desired solution path, you'll reach the intermediate already visited state, and decide not to extend your search.

In conclusion, your IDDFS will find a solution if it exists, but not necessarly the shortest.